# How to enable Transport Layer Security between Kibana and Elasticsearch to configure Alerts and Actions

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

Currently we are trying to implement ELK Stack in one of our production server.  While we doing this we are facing some issue in configuring alerts.  Issues is described below

We want to send log monitoring alerts when certain threshold value is reached.

For this we need to configure Transport Layer Security.

We have tried the steps:

**elasticsearch.ssl.certificateAuthorities: [/path/to/elasticsearch-ca.pem]**

**elasticsearch.hosts: ["https://<your_elasticsearch_host>.com:9200"]**

But the below error we have received.

> write EPROTO 140384225970048:error:1408F10B:SSL
> routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version
> number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:

The below are the configuration details

Elasticserach version is 7.8.0.

In elastic search:

xpack.security.enabled: true
xpack.monitoring.collection.enabled: true xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true    xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: certificate    xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.path: security/elastic-ertificates.p12
xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.path:security/elastic-certificates.p12

In Kibana:

server.ssl.enabled: true

server.ssl.certificate: /etc/kibana-7.8.0-linux-x86_64/security/kibana-server-certificate.pem

server.ssl.key: /etc/kibana-7.8.0-linux-x86_64/security/kibana-server-certificate.key

Could you please help to proceed.

Comment: what is version of ES ? what other property you ahve configured related to SSL ? can you please put that as well in questions

Comment: We have added the required details.  Could you please have a look.